# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: photos.forEach is not a function - Parsing unsplash photo API

Tags: javascript

Did i missed something? Im still getting this log:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: photos.forEach is not a function.**
No idea what Im doing wrong.

```
    async fetchImages(baseURL){
    const response = await fetch(baseURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: this.API_KEY
        }
    });
    const photos = await response.json();
    return photos;
}
GenerateHTML(photos){
    photos.forEach(photo => {
        const item = document.createElement('div');
        item.classList.add('item');
        item.innerHTML = `
        <a href='#'>
            <img src="${photo.urls.small}">
            <h3>${photo.user.name}</h3>
        </a>             
        `;
        this.galleryDiv.appendChild(item);
        
    });
}
async getSearchedImages(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchValue = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
    const baseURL = await `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=${searchValue}&client_id=${this.API_KEY}`
    const photos = await this.fetchImages(baseURL);
    this.GenerateHTML(photos);
}
```

}

Comment: `console.log(photos)` and see what the value is

Comment: the json that is returned by the fetch is likely not an irritable object. Your error code says that `photos` does not have a function `.forEach`. Try using `console.log(photos)` before the forEach statement to see what your object looks like

Comment: What's the context for this code? Is it a vanilla JS class? Is it React? Something else?

Comment: @Andy looks like it's in an object

Comment: Haha. Iterable, I think, @asyncawait, not irritable :)

Comment: `baseURL` probably shouldn't be awaited as it's just a string.

Comment: yep, I didint go into array. Tried to pick from photos insted of `photos.results` @sc0rp1on Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos), the response is served as

```
{
  "total": 133,
  "total_pages": 7,
  "results": [
    //Photos here
   ]
}
```

So you should change the function GenerateHTML

```
GenerateHTML(photos){
    photos.results.forEach(photo => {
        const item = document.createElement('div');
        item.classList.add('item');
        item.innerHTML = `
        <a href='#'>
            <img src="${photo.urls.small}">
            <h3>${photo.user.name}</h3>
        </a>             
        `;
        this.galleryDiv.appendChild(item);
        
    });
}
```